# How to use the jQuery-KingTable plugin? (Example does not seem to load)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am searching for a jQuery table plugin which have multiple features such as filtering and I'm using xampp.

I found [jQuery-KingTable](https://github.com/RobertoPrevato/jQuery-KingTable) but when I downloaded the example from GitHub and opened index.html I could only see the table header and there were no rows of data.

How to use the jQuery-KingTable plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the example is trying to load server-side data.

The [jQuery-KingTable](https://github.com/RobertoPrevato/jQuery-KingTable/) project already explains this here: [Working Modes](https://github.com/RobertoPrevato/jQuery-KingTable#modes)

Near the end of index.html you will see one line specifying the `url` property. You can use the `data` property instead.

**Replace this**

```
url: "/api/colors",
```

**with this**

```
data: [
  {
    "name": "Absolute Zero",
    "color": "#0048BA",
    "red": "0%",
    "green": "28%",
    "blue": "73%",
    "hue": "217°",
    "hslSaturation": "100%",
    "hslLight": "37%",
    "hsvSaturation": "100%",
    "hsvValue": "73%"
  },
  {
    "name": "Acid green",
    "color": "#B0BF1A",
    "red": "69%",
    "green": "75%",
    "blue": "10%",
    "hue": "65°",
    "hslSaturation": "76%",
    "hslLight": "43%",
    "hsvSaturation": "86%",
    "hsvValue": "75%"
  }
],
```

The above was a partial copy from the file `/servers/data/colors.json` in that same project.

**Please read the documentation.**

Comment: Thankssss alot !! I was trying to get this for hours.Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Reading manuals can save lives. Be sure to do that next time. :)

Comment: Yeah i will keep this in mind but I wish i was as smart as you :)

Comment: Hey I can ask you one more favor?How to change row items as column and column items as rows,it is very difficult to understand for me

Comment: I think what you're asking deserves a separate question rather than a comment-follow-up.

But personally I think most table plugins don't work that way (if I understand your question correctly). Most tabular data would have well-defined columns (if not fixed number of columns), and theoretically N (unlimited) number of rows, and not the other way around.

For example, a file explorer would have columns like "Name", "Type", "Size", then N number of rows. When was the last time you see one that has a row called "Name", "Type", "Size", then N number of columns?